# Ignore functions on $watch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects. Some of the properties of this object are functions that return values based on the data for this object. For example

```html
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var с = function(){ return a + b};
```

I need to include this object in $watch(). But  $watch () will go in a cycle (possibly infinite) on the properties of functions. But to get rid of these functions, it is unfortunately not possible. Is it possible to somehow include ignoring all functions in an object on $watch()?

Answer (score 0):

Try and rethink the problem, why not loop through you object and angular.copy() all the non-function elements into a clean array and use watch on that object instead.

btw, you code snippet should read like this if it is one object

```
var obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: function(){ return a + b};
}
```